# How to visualize a Panda with a lot of columns interactively?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: plotting a panda]

I have a panda with a 200+ columns, that I plot currently with

```
ranked.plot.line(figsize=(20,10),title='Rank Over Time')
```

I would like to interactively look at one or several at a time. Ideally tracing the line for exact values. How can I do this in my Jupyter Notebook with my dataframe please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interactive plotting library `Plotly` in your Jupyter Notebook.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = ...

# you can generate an interactive line plot using Plotly Express
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns)

fig.update_layout(
    title='Rank Over Time',
    xaxis_title='Time',
    yaxis_title='Rank',
    hovermode='closest'  # this will enable data tracing when you hover over the plot
)


fig.show()
```

The `px.line()` will create an interactive line plot and it takes your dataframe as input, with the x-values being the DataFrame index and the y-values being all the columns of the DataFrame.